# How to calculate exponent with loop?

Tags: java

I am currently working on a program that calculates the power of certain numbers. The number limit is 1 to 9. My code is posted below. I have the following issues:

1. Every time I run the program it doesn't print the correct answer.
2. I want to modify the code so the application calculates X to power of Y, where X and Y are allowed to be integers in the range 1 to 9 (including 9). If the user enters an invalid value the program should ask the user for input again. When a user is done with entering the values for base and exponents, the program will print the result.

Conditions of this task is that I must use loops to calculate the result by doing 
several multiplications; I am not allowed to use any available method or API 
that calculates the result for me. Please help me come up with the solution.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package exponent;
//import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int b,e;

    System.out.println("Enter the base");
    b = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter the power");
    e = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int t = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i <= e; i++);
    {
        t=t*b;
    }
    System.out.println(t);

    }
    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

Comment: For part two, it only can be a single digit number?

Answer (score 6):

For a start, there should be no semi colon after the for loop:

```
for(int i=1;i<=e; i++ )
        {
            t=t*b;
        }
```

A simple input test could be something along the lines of:

```
public boolean testInput(int e)
{
if(e>9||e<1)//where e is the inputted number
{
return false
}
else 
{
return true;
}

}
```

Then use it like this:

```
  boolean valid = false;
  while(valid!=true)
  {
  e = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  if(testInput(e)==false)
  {
  System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 9")
  continue;
  }
  else
  {
  valid = true;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Actually this could be **the** problem.

Comment: Just to let you know, there is no problem with duplicate answers. The site doesn't always update in realtime. It was nice of the other guy to delete his answer though.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi I was merely telling the other answerer that the answer had already been posted

Comment: @imulsion, the difference between two posts is less than a minute, although the post is now deleted.

Comment: @imulsion I decided to delete my post not because I was obliged to, but because I don't think my duplicate post was needed.  For the record, +1 for identifying the issue and posting before me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove semi colon from for-loop

From

```
 for(int i=1;i<=e; i++ );
```

to

```
 for(int i=1;i<=e; i++ )
```

Comment: nice, i corrected that. It works now. can u please give me the clue to solve the other problem? I will be grearful to u..

Comment: @JabirAlFatah check my answer for part 2 of your question

Comment: I went thorough ur code @imulsion, but i dont get where should i replace the code. can u be more specific?

Comment: @JabirAlFatah the first part of my code is a separate method, so declare it outside of anything else (except your class declaration) and the second part fits in where you want to test your inputs

Comment: Thanks i figured that out ,

Comment: @JabirAlFatah in that case, please consider accepting my answer (click the green tick under the upvote/dpwnvote counter)

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, its is a easy fix. You just added a semicolon where there shouldn't be in the for loop.

```
for(int i = 1;i <= e; i++); {

for(int i = 1;i <= e; i++){ //There should be no semicolon here
```

For the second part, you can do it with two very easy do-while loops.

```
//Replace this
System.out.println("Enter the base");
b = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.println("Enter the power");
e = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

//with
do{
    System.out.println("Enter the base");
    b = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
}while(b > 9 || b < 1);

do{
    System.out.println("Enter the power");
    e = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
}while(e > 9 || e < 1);
```

So the do-while loops, will first ask for the base or the power (Depending where in the code the program is running), then it will set the int to the value. If the value is greater than 9, ie: 10 or above, the program will reask for the base or power (Like I said, depended which loo is running), and then it will set the int again. It will do this, until the value is under 10. Like you want.

Here is an example of the output:

```
Enter the base
56
Enter the base
-4
Enter the base
4
Enter the power
67
Enter the power
10
Enter the power
-8
Enter the power
7
4 to the 7th power is 16384
```

If the code snippets are confusing, here is the entire compilable, working class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class StackOverflowAnswers{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int b,e;

        do{ //Asks for the base
            System.out.println("Enter the base");
            b = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
        }while(b > 9 || b < 1); //If the base is not valid, it goes back to the "do" statement, which asks for the base, again.

        do{ //Asks for the power
            System.out.println("Enter the power");
            e = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
        }while(e > 9 || e < 1); //If the power is not valid, it goes back to the "do" statement, which asks for the power, again.

        int t = 1;

        for(int i = 1;i <= e; i++){ //No semicolon here
            t=t*b;
        }
        System.out.println(b + " to the " + e + "th power is " + t); //Just added some words and the base and the power for easier debugging and understanding.
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think u have misunderstanding about my question. I meant the input values are only allowed in a range from 1 to 9 (including 1 and 9). So the program will calculate the result as soon as the user input the correct values. if the user inputs invalid number (less than 1 or greater than 9) the program should ask the user to re-enter the number.

Comment: @JabirAlFatah That is exactly what the do-while loops do, the program asks for an input, if it is invalid, it will ask again until the value is valid, then after, it will calculate the result.

Comment: Thanks to all of u, I was able to figure that out later

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, it is just happening because you placed a semicolon after loop's declaration, which java just loops to that semicolon and nothing more. By removing semicolon the loop should work. However, for the second part, you can just add inputcheck method, as shown in my code below.

```
import java.io.*;
public class abc {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int b, e;
    System.out.println("Enter the base");
    b = check(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
    System.out.println("Enter the power");
    e = check(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
    int t = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= e; i++); {
        t = t * b;
    }
    System.out.println(t);
}

private static int check(int x) {
    while (x < 1 || x > 10)
        x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I get the error by running your codes at the line:                      b = check(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())); [Error: Non-static method check(int) can't be referenced from a static context]                           e = check(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));                             x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); [Error: can't find the variable br]                                                                     By the way u clearly got my question.

Comment: user2984602, i am still now waiting for your answer.

Comment: @JabirAlFatah I fixed the error in their code, a static method is an method that belongs the the class, a non static method is a method that belongs to an object created from the class. All I did was, made the method static, so it can be used i the class without making an instance of the class (making an object from the class), and made it private so it can only be used in the class itself. Also, I clarified my own answer, so its easier to understand what exactly is happening. Hope this helps.